# Creating helper functions to re-use in my redux reducer code to mutate state

Tags: reactjs, redux

In one of my reducers I am performing some elaborate logic to mutate the state using a reducer.

```
case Constants.MOVE_PRODUCT:      
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.reduce((acc, product) => {
          // code here
        }, [])
    };
```

Now I have to re-use this logic, and wondering how I can wrap this into a function.

Also, if I am creating special functions for my reducers, what is a good place to put these type of helper functions in my react redux project?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you can simply wrap this into a function like:

```html
//-------OPTION 1

//on helper file
function doStuff = (acc, product){
  //logic here
  return newProductsList;
}

//on reducer file
import {doStuff} from '../helpers/myHelper'
case Constants.MOVE_PRODUCT:      
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.reduce((acc, product) => doStuff, [])
    };




//-------OPTION 2

//on helper file
const doAnotherStuff = (products) => products.reduce((acc, product) => {
 //logic here
},[]);


//on reducer file
import {doAnotherStuff} from '../helpers/myHelper'
case Constants.MOVE_PRODUCT:      
  return {
    ...state,
    products: doAnotherStuff(state.products)
 };
```

For your helper functions, it would depend on your project structure and how you organize it. You could create a helper folder to add your helpers there. There is no wrong and right, something could suit better for you and your project than for others.